# Why does the eccentricity vector equation always equal -1?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, mathematics

This is the eccentricity vector equation,
$$e=\frac{1}{\mu}[(v^2-{\mu \over r})r-(r \cdot v)v]$$
$$e=|e|$$
Now this equation is written differently from many different sources but they essentially mean the same thing. I tried this equation out and no matter what values I gave to the variables, the answer is always -1 (or 1 in absolute terms). I understand that the eccentricity of a parabola is 1 but this equation is for ellipses as well. So why is the answer always -1? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression on the right is meant to give the eccentricity *vector* but the vector notation has been lost.

Here it is in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/4730/12102):

$$ e = {v^2 r \over {\mu}} - {(r \cdot v ) v \over{\mu}} - {r\over{\left|r\right|}}$$

and the vector nature is not clear either. We should write it as

$$ \mathbf{e} = {v^2 \mathbf{r} \over {\mu}} - {(\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{v} ) \mathbf{v} \over{\mu}} - {\mathbf{r}\over{r}}$$

where the bold face represents vectors and $v=|\mathbf{v}|$ and $r=|\mathbf{r}|$, or as

$$ \mathbf{e} = {|\mathbf{v}|^2 \mathbf{r} \over {\mu}} - {(\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{v} ) \mathbf{v} \over{\mu}} - {\mathbf{r}\over{\left|\mathbf{r}\right|}}$$

In the expression $(\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{v} ) \mathbf{v}$ the term $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ is a vector dot product, and return a scalar, which then multiplies the vector $\mathbf{v}$.

Here's a quick calculation to confirm it. I chose $\mu=1$ and $a=1$ so that the orbital period is $2 \pi$. You can see that the eccentricity vector x component is +0.8 and constant, and the y component is 0.0 That confirms that the eccentricity vector always points towards the direction of periapsis and *it's magnitude* is always equal to the scalar eccentricity, which in this case is 0.8

[image: orbit and eccentricity vector]

Python script:

```
def deriv(X, t):
    x, v = X.reshape(2, -1)
    acc = -x * ((x**2).sum())**-1.5
    return np.hstack((v, acc))

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ODEint

halfpi, pi, twopi = [f*np.pi for f in (0.5, 1, 2)]
e     = 0.8
peri  = 1. - e
apo   = 1. + e

vperi = np.sqrt(2./peri - 1.)  # vis-viva equation

X0    = np.array([peri, 0] + [0, vperi])
times = np.linspace(0, twopi, 201)

answer, info = ODEint(deriv, X0, times, full_output=True)

r, v = answer.T.reshape(2, 2, -1)
vsq  = (v**2).sum(axis=0)
rabs = np.sqrt((r**2).sum(axis=0))

evec = vsq*r - (r*v).sum(axis=0) * v - r/rabs

if True:
    x, y = r

    plt.figure()

    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.plot([0], [0], 'oy', markersize=16) # the Sun
    plt.xlim(-2, 0.5)
    plt.ylim(-1.25, 1.25)

    plt.subplot(4, 1, 3)
    plt.plot(times/twopi, x)
    plt.plot(times/twopi, y)
    plt.title('x, y', fontsize=16)

    plt.subplot(4, 1, 4)
    x, y = evec
    plt.plot(times/twopi, x)
    plt.plot(times/twopi, y)
    plt.title('evec_x, evec_y', fontsize=16)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96249/discussion-on-answer-by-uhoh-why-does-the-eccentricity-vector-equation-always-eq).

Comment: @uhoh Just to clarify, the vector dot product will always be 0 in a circular orbit right? Because the angle between where my velocity is taking me and the radius is always 90 degrees. And in a elliptical orbit, the vector dot product is 0 at apoapsis and periapsis.

Comment: @StarMan yep that's true. For a circular orbit, or for any periapsis and the apoapsis of an ellipse, $\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{r}$ will be zero. As a quick check: for a circle with $e=0$, if the 2nd term on the right is zero, you have $0 = v^2 r / mu - 1$ which gives $v^2 = mu / r$ which is the [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) for a circular orbit where $r=a$.